# GUI recommendations for eventual consistency?

Tags: user-interface, distributed, cqrs, eventual-consistency

When using distributed and scalable architecture, eventual consistency is often a requirement.

Graphically, how to deal with this eventual consistency?

Users are used to click save, and see the result instantaneously... with eventual consistency it's not possible.

How to deal with the GUI for such scenarios?

Please note the question applies both for desktop applications and web applications.

PS: I'm working with the Microsoft platform, but I imagine the question applies to any technology...

Comment: possible duplicate of [CQRS - Eventual Consistency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414277/cqrs-eventual-consistency)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [Task Based UI](http://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/task-based-ui/) fits this model great. You create and execute tasks from the UI. You can also have something like a task status monitor to show the user when a task has executed.

Another option is to use some kind of pooling from the client. You send the command, and pool from the client until the command completed and the new data is available. You will have a delay in some cases from when the user presses save to when he will see the new record, but in most cases it should be almost synchronous.

Another (good?) option is to assume/design commands that don't fail. This is not trivial but you can have a cache on the client and add the data from the command to that cache and display it to the user even before the command has been executed. If the command fails for some unexpected situation, well then just design a good "we are sorry" message for misleading the user for a few seconds.

You can also combine the methods above.

Usually eventual consistency is more of a business/domain problem, and you should have your domain experts handle it.

Comment: Unfortunately the "Task Based UI" link is now broken.

Comment: Apparently the cqrsinfo.com domain is lost to spam. This [link](http://cqrs.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/cqrs_documents.pdf) seems to have a collection of documents bundled into a pdf

Comment: It appears that the Task Based UI document is now [here](http://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/task-based-ui/)

Answer (score 7):

I think that other answers mix together CQRS in general and eventual consistency in particular. Task-based UI is very suitable for CQRS but it does not resolve the issue with eventually consistent read model.

First, I would like to challenge your statement:

> Users are used to click save, and see the result instantaneously... with eventual consistency it's not possible.

What do you by this? Why is it not possible to see *the result* immediately? I think the issue here is your *definition of result*.

The result of any action is that that action has been performed. There are numerous of ways to show this! It depends on what kind of action do you want to complete. Examples:

- Send an email: if user has entered a correct email address, it is almost guaranteed that the action will complete successfully. To prevent unexpected failures one might use durable queues since this kind of actions do not need to be done synchronously. So you just say "email sent". Typically you see this kind of response when you ask to reset your password.
- Update some information in a user profile: after you have validated the new data on the client, most probably the command will succeed too since the only thing that could happen is the database error (if you use database). Again, even this can be mitigated by using durable queues. In this case you just show the updated field in the same form. The good practice for SPA is to have a comprehensive data store on the client side, like Redux does. In this case you can safely update the server by sending a command and also updating the client-side store, which will result in UI to shows the latest data. *Disclaimer: some answers refer to this technique as "tricking the user", but I disagree with this definition.*
- If you have commands that are prone to error, you can use techniques that are already described in other answers like Websockets or Server-side events to communicate errors back. This requires quite a lot of additional work. You can also send a command and wait for reply or execute commands synchronously. Some would say "this is not CQRS" but this would be just another dogma to be challenged. Ensuring the command has completed the execution in combination with the previous point (client-side data store) will be a good solution.

I am not sure if there is any 100% bullet proof technique that allows you to always show non-stale data from the read model. I think it goes against the principles of CQRS. Even with real-time events you will only get events that indicate that you write model has been updated. Still, your projections could have failed and reacting on this is a whole other story.

However, I would not concentrate that much on this issue. The fact is that well-tested projections and almost-guaranteed commands will work very well. For error handling in 90% of situations it is enough to have some manual or half-manual process to recover from those errors. For the last 10% you can combine generic "error" messages pushed from the server saying "sorry, your action XXX has failed to execute" and the top priority actions could have some creative process behind them but in reality those situations would be very very rare.

Comment: Interesting point of view. I will hardly be able to prototype your suggestion, as the project has been shut down for long now, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 ways:

1. To trick a user (just to show that things has happened then they
   really hasn't happened yet)
2. Show that system is processing request
   and use polling in background (not good) or just timer with value of
   your SLA.

I prefer the 1st option.

Comment: the 1st seems good for user perception if applicable. By applicable, I suppose I have to target a high success percentage (95% maybe) of issuing commands, and provide async callback messages for errors

Comment: Yeah, you should provide percent of success command as high as possible

Answer (score 2):

As someone has already mentioned, task based UI's fit well for this, and what I would do is employ a technique that 'buys you time' for the command to propagate.

For example, imagine we are on a list screen, where the user can perform various actions, one of which being to add a new item to the list. After choosing to add an item you could display a "What would you like to do next?" which could have 'Add another item', 'Do this task', 'Do some other task', 'Go back to list'.

By the time they have clicked on an option, the data would have hopefully been refreshed.

Also, if you're using a task based UI, you can analyse the patterns of task execution and use these "what would you like to do next" screens to streamline the UI. Similar to amazon's "other people also bought these items".

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to handle eventual consistency. All of them are really to occupy the time from the User's action until the backend refresh.

1. **User Reads** A given user can only read from the same database node that they write to. Other users read from the replicated nodes. PROS: UI is quick enough, and application stays in sync. CONS: Your service architecture has to track and route Users to specific database nodes.
2. **Disable the UI** until the action has completed, and refresh it. Java Server Faces has a classic example of this. One could create a modal with a loading spinner to cover the UI until the refresh was completed. PROS: UI stays in sync with application state. CONS: Most every action creates a blocked UI. Users get very frustrated by the restricted UI, and will complain of application slowness.
3. **Confirmation** Immediately thank the user for their submission. Then let them know later (email, SMS, in-app notification) whether or not the action was completed. PROS: It's fast up front. CONS: UI lags behind system until refresh. Even with a notice, the User may get confused that they don't see the updates.  It also requires integration of various communication channels. Users won't see their changes right away. If the action fails, they may not know until it's too late.
4. **Fake it** Optimistically assume that the action will complete. Show the User the resulting UI (upvote, comment, credit card confirmation, etc) and allow them to continue as if it succeeded. If there were failures, immediately show them as contextual errors: alerts next to the undone upvotes, in-app alert on the post with the failed comment, email for the declined credit card. PROS: UI feels much faster. CONS: UI is temporarily out of sync with application state, and you must resolve that. One case: you might fake creation of content with temp IDs. But after content is created, then the temp IDs will be wrong until the refresh. Second case, you might need to store all state changes on the UI after the action until the refresh. Then you need some Resolver to apply all the local state changes since the action was issued. This is resolution is non-trivial.
5. **Web Sockets** Subscribe the UI to an event stream so that when the action is completed on the backend, it is pushed to the front end. Is it one-way or two-way streaming? PROS: UI feels fast, and it's in sync with the application state. CONS: Consistent browser support, need a backend source of streaming events, and socket server scalability.

Answer (score 1):

As previously stated, it is fine to tell the user that the *request* (*command*) has been **acknowledged** (successfully **issued**). In case of some failure, the system should communicate this to the *requester*, by means of:

- email;
- SMS;
- ***custom inbox* (e.g. like the SO inbox)**;
- whatever.

E.g., mail client / service:

- I am sending a mail to a wrong address;
- the mail service says: "email sent successfully :)";
- after few minutes, I receive a mail from the service: "email could not be delivered".

I believe a great way to inform the user about a recent failure **is to present him an error panel while he's navigating through the application**. A user gesture might be required in order to dismiss that alert etc.

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't go with tricking the user or blocking him from committing some other actions. I would rather go for streaming data toward UI after they are being acknowledged by a read side. Let's consider these two cases:

1. Users saves data and expects result. Connection is established toward server. After they are being acknowledged by a read side, they are streamed toward UI and UI is being updated.
2. User saves data and refreshes web page. Upon reload, data are being fetched from data store and connection for streaming is established. If read side didn't update the data store in the meantime, there's still an opened stream and UI should be updated after data reaches the read side.

Why streaming from read side and not directly from write side? Simply, that would be a confirmation that read side has been reached.
From technical aspect, [Server-Sent Events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) could be used.

**Disadvantage:**

Results will still not be reflected immediately by a read side. But at least, in most cases, user will be able to continue with his work without being blocked by a UI.